# Python3 segfaults on OSX, works on Linux and windoze, tk libraries issue perhaps

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm fairly experienced in Python, but a total noob on OSX. I've been using it for a couple of years on windoze then linux OK. Unfortunately I now need to port stuff to an iMac with El Capitain 10.11.3.

I checked out the guides before I tried to install it, in particular the issues around the versions of the tk/tcl libraries. I therefore visited ActiveState, and installed the latest version, then python 3.5.1. This is something that I have never done with 'doze or 'nux.

Simple text programs run OK, whether from IDLE/run, python3 progname, or shebang. The following simple tki program also runs OK, also from those three launch methods.

```
#! /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3

import tkinter as tki

def cmd():
    print('doing command')
    exit()

root = tki.Tk()
but = tki.Button(root, text='hello', command=cmd)
but.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

But when I try to run a sizeable tki based app, it complains that it has found classes TKApplication, TKMenu, TKContentView and TKWindow in both /Library/Frameworks/... which is where python is installed, and /System/Library/Frameworks/... which is presumably where the tcl/tk install from ActiveState went. It then exits with a segfault 11. The app is basically low level tk stuff, just a lot of it. Both locations include /Versions/8.5/ in the name.

I suspect the key is that it says which one of each of those TKxx will be used is undefined. Perhaps it's picking a mix of those, and so when they go to talk to each other, they are not in predictable locations.

Is this what's happening? Why does the simple tk app work but not the complex one, is it the size, or the need to use several classes from different libraries?

As there seems to be a set of tk libraries in the python tree, I'm inclined to remove the ActiveState ones. Is this sensible? How do I do this (Mac noob alert)!

I don't seem to be able to find a definitive 'how to' install python 3 on OSX. Not found too much specifically for 10.11.3, could this OSX version need a different procedure?

Comment: I would imagine there's some conflict happening mucking things up, hence the err. I would recommend installing other versions of Python you need with MacPorts, virtualenv, or build it from source yourself — MacPorts is likely the most simple route.

Comment: Ah, therin lies the problem. I'm just a user, albeit the domestic sysadmin by default. I'm trying to do this without becoming a developer. This means no building from source, no virtualenv, just putting a single version of Python on. I've had a quick look at macports, 5112 results when search for python! I already have text and simple tki working, I'll persist with trying to trouble shoot the existing install fort he moment.

Comment: You need to track down where the error is. Post your actual error.

Comment: Also try using the MacPorts Tcl/Tk instead of ActiveState.